# Trying to add photos from web API to individual rows in table

Tags: ios, image, uitableview

I have a UITable which I would like to add photos to on the left side of the cells.  The photos are currently coming from my showStream method (see code below).  All of the photos get added to just the first cell of my UITable. How can I get each photo added to a single cell so that each cell in my UITable shows one of the images (images separated by the rows)? Can I call the UITableViewCell method and somehow put a single photo in each row?

```
-(void)showStream:(NSArray*)stream 

{
// 1 remove old photos
for (UIView* view in _tableView.subviews) 
{
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}

// 2 add new photo views
for (int i=0;i<[stream count];i++) 
    {

    NSDictionary* photo = [stream objectAtIndex:i];
    PhotoView* photoView = [[PhotoView alloc] initWithIndex:i andData:photo];
    photoView.delegate = self;
```

// here I set up the cell
          UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

```
    if (cell == nil) {


        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [array addObject:photo];

    }
}
```

Here is the tableView method....can I pass something in where the question marks are?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

can I get the photo array inside this method?

    }



return cell;
}
```

Comment: Highly unlikely that '_tableView addSubview:' is correct. Show your table view data source & delegate methods.

Comment: See edit. Is it possible to set the cell.imageView.image to the photoView instance in the showStream method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save your images in an `NSArray` or similar because you must configure the cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Whenever the table view reloads it will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and it expects the cells to be returned with suitable content for the supplied index path.

You could setup each cell in your `showStream:` but it's much easier just to save all the images there and then `reloadData` at the end. Then you don't need to do any pre-setup of the table view to tell it how many rows + sections it has, do any visibility checks (to ensure the cells are on display) for the rows you're trying to update, ... - reuse the functionality supplied by the table view...

Something more like:

`showStream:` (store all your new views into an array, photoList)

```
self.photoList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSDictionary* photo = [stream objectAtIndex:i];
PhotoView* photoView = [[PhotoView alloc] initWithIndex:i andData:photo];
photoView.delegate = self;

[self.photoList addObject photoView];
```

`cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (create the cell if required, clean the cell, add the photo view)

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

[cell.contentView addSubview:[self.photoList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: I set up the cell in the stream method, but how can I use that array inside the tableView method where the indexPath is set?  Thanks

Comment: So the only error Im getting is:  "Use of Undeclared Indentifier indexPath" on the last line of your code

Comment: The code using the index path goes in '- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath'. Wherever you currently have the 'if (cell == nil) {' code it sounds like it's wrong.

Comment: hmmm. No warnings or crashes but nothing appears in the table. Just a white blank UITable.

Comment: have you logged / debugged to check that the table view methods are being called ?

Comment: Added a break point to the tableView method and there were no breaks....so it looks like the tableView is not getting called.

Comment: so you need to check that your controller is set as the dataSource and delegate of the table view when the table is created.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30703/discussion-between-user1639594-and-wain)